# Only allow one RadioButton selection in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, radio-button

I have some RadioButtons in Tkinter (Python 3). These are `btOrange` and `btPurple`. I need to make sure that only one of them can be selected at a time. How can I do this?

My code:

```
from tkinter import *

class MyPaint:

    color = "Black"

    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk()


        self.canvas = Canvas(window, width = 750, height = 500, bg = "white")
        self.canvas.pack()

        colorFrame = Frame(window)
        colorFrame.pack()

        btOrange = Radiobutton(colorFrame, text = "Orange", bg = "Orange", command = self.setColor("Orange"))
        btPurple = Radiobutton(colorFrame, text = "Purple", bg = "Purple", command = self.setColor("Purple"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tie two or more radio buttons together by having them share a variable. For example:

```
self.colorVar = StringVar()
btOrange = Radiobutton(..., variable=self.colorVar, value="Orange")
btPurple = Radiobutton(..., variable=self.colorVar, value="Purple")
```

In this case, `self.colorVar` will be automatically set to whichever radio button is selected.